# Unable to compile JSP in Struts

Tags: jsp, struts

I'm unable to compile JSP in Struts. I am getting `JasperException` at line 20. I have included all jars required to tackle taglib files.

```
17:<form action="/login.do?method=authUser" >
18:    <div align="center">
19:    <table>
20:        <tr><td><label>UserName</label></td><html:text property="username"/></tr>
21:        <tr><td><label>Password</label> </td><html:password property="passwd"/></tr>
22:    </table>
23:    <html:submit value="LogIn"/><html:submit value="SignUp" onclick="gotoSignuUp();"/>
24:</form>
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting.PLease post stack trace

Comment: Have you tried td with end tag

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing this error ***org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The Struts dispatcher cannot be found*** then you may be missing struts filter in your web.xml:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Also check ***struts html library*** in your jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html"%>
```

**Note:** If you can post complete error code then we can pinpoint exact problem and give according solution.